# glibc on OpenSUSE 13.2

Tags: kernel, glibc, opensuse, suse

I would like to get the last version of the glibc (2.22)
I've tried different things

1) With zypper

```
sudo zypper update glibc
```

But I have the highest avalaible version (glibc-2.19...)

2) By installing some rpm packages

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to get the last version of the glibc (2.22)

In general, distributions *never* update the glibc version from the one they initially shipped with, because that can break existing binaries in many unexpected ways.

You *can* install glibc-2.22 on your system by building it from source, but beware: doing it incorrectly will likely render your system un-bootable.

You can also install glibc-2.22 *in parallel* to  your existing one, and use it for just the few programs that need it. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).